# Rails: Form with configurable number of inputs

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, erb

I wrote a form that generates a text input for each property.
The list of properties is configurable by the customer.

```
<% properties = ["refractivity_at_2kHz", "refractivity_at_5kHz"] %>

<% properties.each do |property| %>
  <div class="property">
    <%= f.label property %>
    <%= f.text_field property %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

It fails with the error `undefined method refractivity_at_2kHz`.

What is the usual solution for this problem?

Should I add an array to my model, and use `f.text_field myarray[property]` ?

Comment: Does model you creates form for has all these properties?

Comment: @Bohdan: No. Properties are really dynamic, the client can modify them at any time.

Comment: Kai is right then if you use `f.text_field(property)` it expects that object has this property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it a `form_for(@model)`?

Because then `f.text_field(property)` looks for that method/property on `@model`.

May be you want to change `f.text_field(property)` into `text_field_tag(property)`[1]

cheers

[1] http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-text_field_tag

Comment: Yes, it is in a form_for block. I just had a look at text_field_tag, it seems like it might allow me to process form results manually :-)

Comment: I will be back as soon as I manage to use text_field_tag http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6593263 (--')

Comment: Hey maybe you could serialize the properties and than do something similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1002963/how-to-edit-a-rails-serialized-field-in-a-form that

Comment: Thanks, a serialized field is just what I needed!

Comment: Just a note: Did you really mean `f.text_field_tag` or rather `text_field_tag` ?

Comment: nope that was a typo, meant `text_field_tag` - sorry about that