# Rails: undefined method text_field_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, erb

My ERB file works fine if I use `text_field`, but if I switch to `text_field_tag` I receive this error:

```
undefined method `text_field_tag' for #<ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder:0x00000001f6fd50>
```

Here is the code that works:

```
<%= f.text_field mystring %>
```

And the code that does not work:

```
<%= f.text_field_tag mystring %>
```

[text_field_tag](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-text_field_tag) is documented. How to make it work? Do I need a `require` or something?

Comment: text_field_tag isnt a method of FormBuilder - its a view_helper like `link_to` so just use `text_field_tag`  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your information, `text_field_tag` is from `ActionView::Helpers::FormTagHelper`, which states :

> Provides a number of methods for
>   creating form tags that doesn’t rely
>   on an Active Record object assigned to
>   the template like FormHelper does.
>   Instead, you provide the names and
>   values manually.

Since this is a helper that does not rely on an active record object, you cannot call this method for the "f" object. It's a a helper method that should be called like this :

```
<%= text_field_tag "whatever you want to write" %>
```

Answer (score 2):

Needed to remove f:

```
<%= text_field_tag mystring %>
```

I guess text_field_tag does not rely on the form_for.

Comment: yea text_field belongs to the form_for, in the sense you need to use with an object, while text_field_tag is much more flexible. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-text_field_tag  and http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html