# How to deal with serialized field in rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a serialized field in my model

```
class Screen < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :options
end
```

The user should be able to add / edit n number of options for each record. I saw this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1002963/how-to-edit-a-rails-serialized-field-in-a-form) and tried

```
<%= f.fields_for :options do |o| %>
  <%= o.label :axis_y %>
  <%= o.text_field :axis_y %>
  <%= o.label :axis_x %>
  <%= o.text_field :axis_x %>
<% end %>
```

but my problem is I don't know what are the fields user want to add, and user can specify variable number of attributes for`options`. What is the best/proper way to to do this ? Any help much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen `serialize` before, so I looked it up. [Here's](http://thelazylog.com/using-serialize-option-in-ruby-on-rails/) a tutorial; apparently you need to specify the type of the serialized object as well:

```
serialize :options, Hash
```

To whitelist the hash attrributes, you have a couple options.

You could create a custom validator (see [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-validators) for instructions)

You can also overwrite the `options=` method:

```
def options=(val)
  whitelisted_keys = ["some", "keys"]
  if val.is_a?(Hash) && val.keys.all? { |key| whitelisted_keys.include? key }
    super
  else
    errors.add(:options, "is invalid")
    self
  end
end
```

You also might need to configure your `screen_params` method, so if things aren't working show that code in your question.

Comment: tanks for you help. The real problem here is how to use this field in the form. I can't ask my users to fill in a hash

Comment: definitely going to need javacript to do dynamic forms